# Ajax table wont filter searches with Datatable pluggin

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a ajax call to create a HTML with data and then call .DataTable to that HTML table. However when trying to make it have multiple filters (each column) the search function doesn't seem to work and when you type in something it just returns nothing. Below is the code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "WCF/WicsReports.svc/userUsageReport?unit=" + unitType + "&startDate=01/09/2014&endDate=01/01/2015&tradingparty=" + tradingPartyVal($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CsUsageLVIUser_ddlTradingParties")),
        contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
        success: function (result) {
            $('.divLVIUserReportData').html(result.UserUsageReportResult);
            $('.loading').hide();

            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#lviDetails tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $('#lviDetails thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });

            // DataTable
            var table = $('#lviDetails').DataTable({
                //"bFilter": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "paging": 50,
                "pagingType": "simple",
                "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],

                initComplete: function () {
                    //$("#lviDetails_filter").hide();

                    var r = $('#lviDetails tfoot tr');
                    r.find('th').each(function () {
                        $(this).css('padding', 8);
                    });
                    $('#lviDetails thead').append(r);
                    $('#search_0').css('text-align', 'center');
                },
            });

            // Apply the search
            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });
            });

        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('.divLVIUserReportData').html("<div class='error_messages'>ERROR: The Ajax service call failed: " + result.status + " " + result.statusText + "</div>");
            $('.loading').hide();
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        afterSend: function () {

        }
    });
```

Any help how to fix this??

Comment: Does it return nothing or display "No records found" (or similar)?

Comment: it returns "No matching records found". Where as if i just use the original filter it works

Comment: This is likely caused by the search being applied to the wrong column (for example: you're actually searching column 3, but looking for values in column 4)